# nsroot, what directories need to be host-specific?

Tags: nfs, root-filesystem, fhs

I'm playing with an nfsroot boot for multiple hosts; Ubuntu has some dated docs that recommend:

```
#/etc/fstab
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/run        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
```

I've notice already that /var/lib/dhcp needs to be mounted additionally otherwise clients conflict with eachother.

I tried for a while, an aggressive /var tmpfs:

```
#/etc/fstab
none            /var            tmpfs   defaults        0       0
```

But i worry about things like Apt, that rely on /var/lib for shared state. <s>This woudln't be the first time apt's file lay our has annoyed me-.</s>

Additionally with the usual /var/run -> /run, /var/lock -> /run/lock, I worry about stepping on soemthing I didn't mean to with that aggressive /var tmpfs, so I'm curious, can anyone recommended a shared-root-fs tmpfs excludes list?

I'm open to introducing symlinks where it makes sense, though I've noticed a lot of applications will wipe them out, <s>not bothering to check if the system is trying to redirect its nonsense-.</s>

Answer (score 0):

this is my current WIP:

```
#/etc/fstab
proc /proc    proc  defaults 0 0
none /tmp     tmpfs defaults 0 0
none /media   tmpfs defaults 0 0

none /var/lib/dhcp  tmpfs   defaults  0  0
none /tmp           tmpfs   defaults  0  0
none /run           tmpfs   defaults  0  0
none /var/tmp       tmpfs   defaults  0  0
```